# android notifydatasetchange() not working

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have an error on `notifydatasetchanged()`. Can anyone give me a proper solution?

I have tried all possible cases but I am not finding a solution.

I have attached `notifydatasetchanged()` as `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` and but it's not working at all and if I give this: `oncreate(null)` it's showing an error in MainActivity.

My `doInBackground` method is:

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if (phones != null) {
            Log.e("count", "" + phones.getCount());
            if (phones.getCount() == 0) {
                Log.d("No Contacts", "No Contacts");
            }

            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
               Bitmap bit_thumb = null;
                String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String image_thumb = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
                try {
                    if (image_thumb == null) {
                       //bit_thumb = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, Uri.parse(image_thumb));
                    } else {
                        bit_thumb = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, Uri.parse(image_thumb));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                SelectUser selectUser = new SelectUser();
                selectUser.setThumb(bit_thumb);
                selectUser.setName(name);
                selectUser.setPhone(phoneNumber);
                selectUser.setCheckedBox();
                selectUsers.add(selectUser);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Cursor close 1", "----------------");
        }
        //phones.close();
        return null;
    }

protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    adapter = new SelectUserAdapter(selectUsers, MainActivity.this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                synchronized (MainActivity.this) {
                    if (firstClickTime == 0) {
                        firstClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                        nonDoubleClick = true;
                    } else {
                        long deltaTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - firstClickTime;
                        firstClickTime = 0;
                        if (deltaTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIMEOUT) {
                            nonDoubleClick = false;
                            this.onItemDoubleClick(adapterView, view, position, l);
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (nonDoubleClick) {
                                Log.d("Single click", "single click");
                            }
                        }

                    }, DOUBLE_CLICK_TIMEOUT);
                }
            }

            public void onItemDoubleClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(com.jamol.contacts.R.id.no)).getText().toString();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.call);
                    mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                    mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    v.vibrate(500);
                    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + selected));
                    startActivity(in);
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Log.e("PERMISSION_EXCEPTION", "PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED");
                }
            }
    });

    listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
}
```

And the adapter is:

```
public SelectUserAdapter(List<SelectUser> selectUsers, Context context) {
    _data = selectUsers;
    _c = context;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(_data);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return _data.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(com.jamol.contacts.R.layout.contact_info, null);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    ViewHolder v = new ViewHolder();

    v.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(com.jamol.contacts.R.id.name);
    v.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(com.jamol.contacts.R.id.check);
    v.setPhone((TextView) view.findViewById(com.jamol.contacts.R.id.no));
    v.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.jamol.contacts.R.id.pic);

    final SelectUser data = _data.get(i);
    v.title.setText(data.getName());
    v.check.setChecked(data.getCheckedBox());
    v.getPhone().setText(data.getPhone());

    try {

        if (data.getThumb() != null) {
            v.imageView.setImageBitmap(data.getThumb());
        } else {
            v.imageView.setImageResource(com.jamol.contacts.R.drawable.ic_user);
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        v.imageView.setImageDrawable(this._c.getDrawable(com.jamol.contacts.R.drawable.ic_user));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    view.setTag(data);
    return view;
}


public void filter(String charText) {
    if (charText != null) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        _data.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            _data.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (SelectUser wp : arraylist)
                if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    _data.add(wp);
                }
        }
    }

}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView title;
    CheckBox check;
    private TextView phone;

    public TextView getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(TextView phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

And this is the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.jamol.contacts, PID: 18190 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131492978, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.jamol.contacts.SelectUserAdapter)]
                                                                        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1584)
                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2645)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16939)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16939)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16939)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
```

Comment: Post your doinbackground(). You are trying to make UI thread call in that function, which is wrong.

Comment: yes posted will you please explain me or correct it my code

Comment: doInBackground seems fine. You do not need to call notifyDataSetChanged just after setAdapter(). Call notifyDataSetChanged() when you modify selectUsers after setting the adapter.

Comment: could you explain me clearly

Comment: In your case, you are fetching the values and putting in the adapter, and then calling setAdapter(). Since you have not made any changes after setAdapter() you do not need to call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: if i remove notifyDataSetChanged() even it is giving same error

Comment: are you modifying selectedUsers somewhere else?

Comment: not so whole code i have posted here

Comment: You are changing _data values in filter(). That is the only possible thing which I think is giving the error. call notifyDataSetChanged() there.

Comment: public void filter(String charText) {
        if (charText != null) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            _data.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                _data.addAll(arraylist);
            } else {
                for (SelectUser wp : arraylist)
                    if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                            .contains(charText)) {
                        _data.add(wp);
                    }
            }
        }
         notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: yes, try this and see what happens.

Comment: even i am getting same error

Comment: now error had gone bt its not updating data

Comment: put notifyDataSetChanged() just after adding data.

Comment: for (SelectUser wp : arraylist)
                    if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                            .contains(charText)) {
                        _data.add(wp);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

Comment: I understand you are trying to do a seach in the ListView, you should consider improving your code. Check out more tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in Activity.
Override this method in adaptor Create one method for getting updated values.

```
    @Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
  public SelectUserAdapter(List<SelectUser> selectUsers, Context context) {
_data = selectUsers;
_c = context;
 updateResults(selectUsers);
}

public void updateResults(List<SelectUser> results) {
    userList = results;//List<SelectUser> userList
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: what is mListDestinationComments

Comment: mListDestinationComment is your list of user

Comment: @Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
  public SelectUserAdapter(List<SelectUser> selectUsers, Context context) {
_data = selectUsers;
_c = context;
 updateResults(selectUsers);
}

public void updateResults(List<SelectUser> results) {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

Comment: i have kept like this but same, i mean i am getting same error

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); Remove this code from onPostExecute